# PostgreSQL - How to change tmp directory?

Tags: postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL on Windows 8 using the OpenGeo Suite.  I'm running out of disk space on a large join.  How can I change the temporary directory where the "hash-join temporary file" gets stored?

I am looking at the PostgreSQL configuration file and I don't see a tmp file directory.

Note: I am merging two tables with 10 million rows using a variable text field which is set to a primary key.

This is my query:

```
UPDATE blocks 
SET "PctBlack1" = race_blocks."PctBlack1"
FROM race_blocks
WHERE race_blocks.esriid = blocks.geoid10
```

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure you have an index on these columns (of both tables). This would make PostgreSQL use less temporary files. Also, set the GUC [`work_mem`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) to as high as possible, to make PostgreSQL use more memory for operations like this.

Now, if still need, to change the temporary path, you first need to create a tablespace (if you didn't do it already):

```
CREATE TABLESPACE temp_disk LOCATION 'F:\pgtemp';
```

Then, you have to set the GUC [`temp_tablespaces`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TEMP-TABLESPACES). You can set it per database, per user, at `postgresql.conf` or inside the current session (before your query):

```
SET temp_tablespaces TO 'temp_disk';

UPDATE blocks 
SET "PctBlack1" = race_blocks."PctBlack1"
FROM race_blocks
WHERE race_blocks.esriid = blocks.geoid10
```

One more thing, the user must have `CREATE` privilege to use this:

```
GRANT CREATE ON TABLESPACE temp_disk TO app_user;
```

Comment: I can create the tablespace on C, but when I do it on F I get: 
"ERROR: could not set permissions on directory "f:/pgtemp": Permission denied"

Comment: I'm running Windows 8 as the Administrator.

Comment: @AaronKreider, the permissions should be set to the user running the PostgreSQL's service, usually named `postgres`.

Comment: How do I change these permissions?  In Windows Control Panel, I only see Administrator, Aaron, and Guest.

Comment: I might be able to create a symbolic link in Windows.

Comment: Ensure the tablespace **does not** reside in temporary storage because if you lose a tablespace (file deletion, disk failure, etc), the database cluster could become unreadable or unable to start. In other words, placing a tablespace on a temporary file system like a ramdisk risks the reliability of the entire cluster (source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html)

Comment: If you want to use the tablespace, make sure the user making the query has access to it. You'll probably want to run `grant create on tablespace temp_space to public;`.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to set the F:/pgtemp directory directly in PostgreSQL due to a lack of permissions.

So I created a symlink to it using the windows command line "mklink /D" (a soft link). Now PostgreSQL writes temporary files to c:\Users\Administrator.opengeo\pgdata\Administrator\base\pgsql_tmp they get stored on the F: drive.

Comment: This worked the first time I tried it, but the next time it caused the OpenGeo suite and PostgreSQL to crash while loading.

Comment: Aaron, were you ever able to diagnose why this crashed, or did the symlink arrangement work out fine for you? Could the crash have been caused by what I've written in the comment I've just left for MatheusOI's answer below?

Comment: Hassan - I'm not sure. I have since moved the entire setup to a new disk with more space.

Comment: Oh so the symlink arrangement never worked out for you eh?

Comment: I'm not sure as it was 3 years ago and I don't remember.  I may have only needed a massive amount of disk space for one or two times and then haven't used it since (as I don't modify that database table that often). I can say that I never intentionally used a ramdisk (unless windows did this automatically)